Using F-test for restricted model vs unrestricted, wrong answer
studying Econometrics I come across this question for which I cannot find the right answer:
Assuming a percentage of household's expenses on food is linearly dependent on the total expenditure and size of household: $$\text{wfood}_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 \text{totexp}_i + \beta_3 \text{size}_i$$Using F-test for restricted and unrestricted models test a hypothesis $H_0$ that coefficients $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ do not depend on the $\text{sex}_i$. The alternative hypothesis is that at least one of $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ vary.
I use
$$F=\frac{(RSS_R-RSS_{UR})/r}{RSS_{UR}/(n-k_{UR})} \sim F_{r, k_{UR}}$$
to test restricted model (first one) against unrestricted (adding $+\beta_4\text{sex(woman)}_i$), but get the wrong value of F-statistic (I have to choose one of the variants, and there's no such value there; expected value is $2.4$ or $24.4$).
How do I do that:
library(Ecdat)
data("BudgetFood")

b <- na.omit(BudgetFood)
model_r <- lm(data = b, wfood ~ totexp + size)
model_ur <- lm(data = b, wfood ~ totexp + size + sex)

r <- 2
n <- count(b)$n
k_UR <- 4

RSS_UR <- deviance(model_ur)
RSS_R <- deviance(model_r)

Fstatistic <- ((RSS_R - RSS_UR) / r) / (RSS_UR / (n - k_UR))

Fstatistic  # 0.145555

qf(0.975, r, n - k_UR)  # 3.689447

I appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

There are a couple of things to review: (a) the number of parameters includes the intercept $\beta_1$, the predictor coefficients $\beta_2,\ldots$ and the residual std dev. $\sigma$; (b) the F-test is one-sided ("more extreme" than observed means "larger than observed"), so use qf(0.95, ...) for significance level $\alpha = 0.95$

@dipetkov, thanks for one-sided, it's my fault. I used 0.95 but changed it to 0.975 for unknown reason:) The trouble is the observed value, which is for an order of magnitude less than it should be.

Did you correct your counting of the number of parameters? The difference between r and k_UR is 2 although the models suggest should be 1.

@dipetkov, in that formula, $r$ is the number of restrictions which does not include intercept, so $r=k-1$. $k_{UR}$ is the number of coefficients in unrestricted model. I think that I'm going in the wrong direction and maybe I need to compare coefficients from both models, but I need covariance to calculate $\dfrac{ | \hat{\beta_j}{UR} - \hat{\beta_j}{R} | }{ se(\hat{\beta_j}{UR} -\hat{\beta_j}{UR}) }$, and furthermore, this statistic supposed to be t-distributed, but the task says F-test. I'm stuck.

Is the correct answer 2.4 or 24.4? I’m confused about why both values get mentioned. // What are you trying to do in that qf line? // The “chunk test” link in my profile may be of interest.

@dave, I didn't know the correct answer but there were two options for observed statistic's value: 2.4 and 24.4. qf(p, df1, df2) returns certain quantile of F-distribution with given degrees of freedom which I supposed to compare with observed statistic and choose the correct option.

From the question I would infer that you should interact all coefficients with sex. Right now, your unrestricted model "only" allows for a gender-specific intercept. It does not allow you to assess, say, if an additional euro of total expenditure has a differential effect for men and women (as an aside: whatever that may mean at the household level, since many households comprise both men and women). In your code, that would amount to model_ur <- lm(data = b, wfood ~ totexp*sex + size*sex)

The correct method is Wald test:
library("lmtest")
model_r <- lm(data = b, wfood ~ totexp + size)
model_ur <- lm(data = b, wfood ~ totexp * sex + size * sex)
waldtest(model_r, model_ur)


Have you verified that this works and gives the correct answer? My first thought was to see what that very function gives, but my code gave an error (I forget what).

@Dave, it gives correct answer.
Wald test
Model 1: wfood ~ totexp + size
Model 2: wfood ~ totexp * sex + size * sex
Res.Df Df      F    Pr(>F)
1  23968
2  23965  3 24.404 9.244e-16 ***
Signif. codes:  0 '' 0.001 '' 0.01 '' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
`

What you run here is an F-test. As I wrote in my comment above, the issue is with the unrestricted model. You have 6 regressors in the unrestricted model and three restrictions in the restricted model. Once you fix that, your code will give you the same test statistic.

As in RSS_UR <- sum(resid(model_ur)^2) RSS_R <- sum(resid(model_r)^2) r <- 3 n <- length(na.omit(b$wfood)) k_UR <- 6 Fstatistic <- ((RSS_R - RSS_UR) / r) / (RSS_UR / (n - k_UR)) 

You are right, it gives exactly the same result as the waldtest(model_r, model_ur)! So, it uses the same formula, and I was wrong choosing the model firstly, and then (when I tried another model), counting number of restrictions.
